# 2 conditional independences between 3 random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose there are 3 random variables $(X, Y, Z)$, such that
$ Y \perp Z | X $ and $ X \perp Z | Y $.

I have convinced myself that it follows that $Z$ is independent of $X, Y$.

$$ p(X, Y, Z) = p(X) p(Y|X) p(Z|X) = p(X, Y) p(Z | X) $$
$$ p(X, Y, Z) = p(Y) p(X|Y) p(Z|Y) = p(X, Y) p(Z | Y) $$

Therefore $p(Z|X) = p(Z|Y)$ but the former is a function of $X$, the latter a function of $Y$, so it must be a constant i.e. $p(Z|X) = p(Z|Y) = p(Z)$.

Finally, plugging back in
$$ p(X, Y, Z) = p(X) p(Y|X) p(Z|X) = p(X, Y) p(Z) $$

Is the above argument correct?

Is there a better/more general proof?